# What is the probability distribution described by this problem?

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose I have a probability of winning a coin toss 90% of the time; it's an extremely unfair coin :). I want to simulate the number of wins after a specified number of coin tosses.

I want to write code that samples the distribution, but I don't know what distribution would match.

Given:

- probability of winning a coin toss (the unfairness of the coin) should be a parameter (I'd actually like to change the unfairness of the coin, so a solution only suitable for the 90% case doesn't really help)
- number of coin tosses

I want to randomly sample the distribution to return the number of wins. Is there a name for the appropriate probability distribution function to simulate this?

Comment: I am aware that I can use a uniform distribution to randomly decide the outcome of a single coin toss, but doing so many times would be computationally expensive, when all I want is the number of times I will win given the number of coin tosses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a known and fixed number of coin tosses $n$, in which the outcome of every coin toss is independent and identically distributed with the same probability of winning $p$, the number of wins $X$ remains a binomially distributed random variable:  $$\Pr[X = k] = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}, \quad k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n.$$  For example, if $n = 12$ and $p = 0.9$, then the probability that you observe $k = 5$ wins is $$\Pr[X = 5] = \binom{12}{5} (0.9)^5 (1 - 0.9)^{12-5} \approx 0.0000467668.$$

However, if your desire is to **simulate** a random process that generates the number of wins according to such a distribution, then simply knowing the probability mass function described above is not enough.  The naive implementation would be to generate $n$ uniform random variates in the range $[0,1]$ and count how many of them are less than or equal to $p = 0.9$.  If $n$ is very large and you want to calculate many realizations of $X$, this could be slow.  So a better way is to pre-compute the cumulative distribution function; i.e., for each $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n$, calculate **by recursion** $$\Pr[X \le k] = \Pr[X \le k-1] + \Pr[X = k].$$  So for the above example, we would have $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X \le 0] &= 1 \times 10^{-12}, \\ \Pr[X \le 1] &= 1.09 \times 10^{-10}, \\ \Pr[X \le 2] &= 5.455 \times 10^{-9}, \\ \Pr[X \le 3] &= 1.65835 \times 10^{-7}, \\ \vdots \end{align*}$$  Then for each desired realization, generate a single uniform random variate $U \in [0,1]$ and determine the *smallest* value in the above list that exceeds $U$, and the $k$ that corresponds to that entry in the list is your value of $X$.  So if you generated $U = 0.275239$, this lies between $\Pr[X \le 9] = 0.110869977745$ and $\Pr[X \le 10] = 0.340997748211$, so this corresponds to $X = 10$.

Comment: I want to simulate it using a robust stats library. Turns out numpy and scipy both have the binomial distribution, so it will be quite simple to generate random numbers from it.

Comment: Well that makes your task a *whole* lot easier, doesn't it!  Good to know you don't need to write the code from scratch.

Comment: Turns out scipy implements binomial using numpy. :)